# Instagram on Android Emulator incampatible device

Tags: android-emulator, instagram, android-virtual-device

I have Installed Instagram on android emulator, but when I open it says:

> INCOMPATIBLE DEVICE
>
> unfortunately this device doesn't seem to meet the
> minimum camera requirements. For more information, please visit
> http://bit.ly/igdevices

Its camera problem, I have not hardware camera installed on my PC and i have set the front camera and rear camera to `Emulated`.

can any one say whats the problem with this config?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#limitations

Comment: @user1929959 nothing about camera? how can this help?

Comment: You could try using [genymotion's emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/). Doesn't help with your current emulator but could work.